# Qual a melhor maneira de apresentar apenas duas casas em um float em java

Tags: java, android

Estou criando uma aplicação simples no android studio, onde eu faço uma divisão e apresento o seu resultado em um EditText, porém gostaria de apresentar apenas duas casas decimais, qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Pode usar assim: `String.format("%.2f", valor);`

Comment: @gato acho que você devia postar isso como uma resposta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize este código para formatar suas casas decimais em float ou double

```
float x = (float) 12.309989;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    editText.setText(df.format(x));
```